# How to show that a problem is easy?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

Let $P$ be a problem that you need to study its difficulty, i.e., NP-hard, Polynomial-time solvable, etc.

> My question is: If I reduce a known polynomial time problem (say,
>   maximum matching in bipartite graph) to $P$, why I can say that $P$ is an
>   easy problem?

---

> My guess is: No, we cannot say that.
>
> Why? Because from an instance of maximum matching problem, $I_{ MM }$,
>   I create an instance of $P$, $I_{ P }$, and then I show that maximum
>   matching is solved with $I_{ MM }\iff P$ is solved with $I_{ P }$.
>
> But what if from another instance of maximum matching problem, $I_{ MM }'$
>   , I create another instance of $P$, $I_{ P }'$, which is hard to
>   solve?

I have read that the reduction is correct and works, for example from sorting to convex hull, but I do not why.

I do not know what I am missing here.

Comment: You need to revisit the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Any problem in $\mathsf{P}$ can be (polytime) reduced to the halting problem, for example. (In fact, any problem in $\mathsf{P}$ can be polytime reduced to *any* non-trivial language, that is any language other than $\emptyset$ or $\Sigma^*$.)

What is true is that if A reduces to B and B is easy, then so is A. In particular, if A polytime reduces to B and B is in $\mathsf{P}$, then A is also in $\mathsf{P}$.

Comment: Thank you. So what I understand is: If I want to show that a problem is easy, I have to reduce it, in polytime, to an easy problem. And if I want to show that a problem is hard, I have to reduce a hard problem, in polytime, to it. (Like the reverse way.)

Comment: That's exactly right.